# how to get the none zero indexes of a sparseMatrix?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

Given a Matrix M:

```
M <- Matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), nrow=3, sparse=T)

M
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dtCMatrix"

[1,] 1 . .
[2,] . . .
[3,] . 1 .
```

how can I extract a list of indexed wich point to none zero values at that cell?
In this case for example a data.frame like this:

```
  x y
1 1 1
2 3 2
```

Comment: can you add which package `Matrix()` comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `which(M==1, arr.ind=TRUE)`

```
     row col
[1,]   1   1
[2,]   3   2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library("Matrix")
M <- Matrix(c(1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), nrow=3, sparse=T)
```

Look inside:

```
str(M)
## Formal class 'dtCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 7 slots
##   ..@ i       : int [1:2] 0 2
##   ..@ p       : int [1:4] 0 1 2 2
##   ..@ Dim     : int [1:2] 3 3
##   ..@ Dimnames:List of 2
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##   .. ..$ : NULL
##   ..@ x       : num [1:2] 1 1
##   ..@ uplo    : chr "L"
##   ..@ diag    : chr "N"

help("dtCMatrix-class")
help("CsparseMatrix-class")
```

A low-level answer:

```
cols <- rep(1:3,diff(M@p))
rows <- M@i+1
cbind(x=rows,y=cols)
```

However, it looks like the `which()` answer given above does indeed take advantage of the sparsity, so it's a better answer:

```
t1 <- new("dtTMatrix", x= c(3,7), i= 0:1, j=3:2,
          Dim= as.integer(c(1e6,1e6)))
which(t1>0,arr.ind=TRUE)
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    4
## [2,]    2    3
```